# How do you run a function on the result of NgFor in Angular2?

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-template

Consider a list of all of the users in your system:

```
  allUsers = {
    a: {name:'Adam',email:'adam@testco.com',level:'admin',group:'Owners'},
    b: {name:'Barbra',email:'Barbra@testco.com',level:'admin',group:'Owners'},
    c: {name:'Chris',email:'Chris@otherplace.net',level:'standard',group:'Managers'},
    d: {name:'Dennis',email:'dsmolek@showman.com',level:'standard',group:'Managers'},
    e: {name:'Elizabeth',email:'eadams@testco.com',level:'standard',group:'Staff'},
    f: {name:'fred',email:'fred@testco.com',level:'visitor',group:'Visitor'},

  }
```

Then a list of the users on a project:

```
usersList = ['a','b','d','f'];
```

So you have a nice easy function to take the user id and lookup the rest of the user details:

```
  getUser(userId){
    console.log('Getting User with Id:', userId);
    if(allUsers[userId]) return allUsers[userId];
  }
```

Then in the template you use *ngFor to loop through the users in the list, but you want to then lookup the full set of details

```
<tr *ngFor="#userId in usersList" #user="getUser(userId)">
  <td>{{user.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Doesn't work... 
Without creating custom components or other more complex stuff I can't figure out how to run the getUser function once per user. I can of course run it over and over like:

```
<td>{{getUser(userId).name}}</td>
```

but this doesn't seem like the best way. 
Is there an easier way to get access to the userId variable and set it as a local variable?

[Here's a plunker of what I've been playing with so far](https://plnkr.co/edit/KXS8n5fErhigNvtr0nUu?p=preview)

Comment: Have you tried putting the userId in curly braces? Like this: #user="getUser({{userId}})"

Comment: can you just filter the list, like this, and then iterate over the someUsers variable instead: `var someUsers = usersList.map(function(x) {
    return allUsers[x];
  })
  `

Comment: mapping might work... I'd have to run it every time the component ran but I like the direction. I haven't tried curly braces, I'm not 100% but I don't think it's the right syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though you can create a variable on ngFor template directive, but that variable can only take value of index, even, odd & last.

Thats why I could use pipe for this case, where you need to pass `usersList` & `allUsers` to custom `@Pipe` getUsers (it will act same as a filter in Angular1).

**Markup**

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of usersList | getUsers: allUsers">
  <td>
    {{user.name}}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{user.email}}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{user.level}}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{user.group}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

**Code**

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'getUsers',
  pure: false
})
export class GetUserPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(){
    this.test = 'Test';
  }
  transform(array:Array<string>, object: any) : any {
    // for..in loop
    let output = [];
    for (var num in array)
    {
      // somehow object goes inner side
      output.push(object[0][array[num]]);
    }
    console.log(output)
    return output;
  }
}
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ICTYBhrkW1CSDR8dMtx7?p=preview)

Comment: This is the direction I went. I'm actually using a UserService so I was able to inject the service straight into the pipe. I still feel modifying the resulting local variable would be useful but the pipe makes it cleaner looking as well.

Answer (score 2):

I like

```
<td>{{getUser(userId).name}}</td>
```

That's what I would use.  It is much easier than creating, say, a pipe/filter.

Even if you could do something with a local template variable, I believe it would get re-evaluated for every item in the list, every change detection cycle, just like the HTML shown above.

See also [ng2: How to create variable in ngFor loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35257455/ng2-how-to-create-variable-in-ngfor-loop), where one of the suggestions is to create a child component, and pass `getUser(userId)` to an input property on that component.

Comment: But if we need to bind value of user object 10 times on UI, then we need to repeat `getUser(userId)` on HTML that many times.. will it be good practice to have it..?

Comment: I agree, running getUser over and over doesn't seem very efficient.

Comment: @PankajParkar, less code is almost always better.  I personally wouldn't write extra code unless there was a demonstrable performance issue.  I.e., avoid premature optimization.  `getUser()` is not a complicated function.

Comment: @Mark Make sense.. Thanks +1

Answer (score 0):

You can have your markup as follows

```
<tr *ngFor="theUser in getTheUsers(usersList)" >
   <td>{{theUser.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

`getTheUsers()` function should be something like this

```
getTheUsers(usersList:string[]){
  return usersList.map(user=> this.allUsers[user]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See also [my alternative approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35257455/how-to-create-variable-in-ngfor-loop/66930412#66930412) which makes use of ng-container, *ngIf with let. Though not ideal, you don't need to create a subcomponent. Basically the expression of the *ngIf creates an object (so the *ngIf is always thruthy thus always rendering the content) and a property on the object contains the computed value. The object is assigned to local variable (using let syntax of *ngIf).