# How to create variable in ngFor loop?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am trying to find out how to create a variable in an `ngFor loop`.

I have a loop like this:

```html
<td *ngFor="#prod of products">
  <a href="{{getBuild(branch,prod)?.url}}">
    {{getBuild(branch,prod)?.status}}
   </a>
</td>
```

You can see the the `getBuild` call has to be repeated multiple times. (Many more times in my actual example).  I would like a way to create this variable in the template once inside the loop and simply reuse it.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Essentially the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162539/how-do-you-run-a-function-on-the-result-of-ngfor-in-angular2

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think local variables (defined with the `#` character) don't apply for your use case.

In fact, when you define a local variable on an HTML element it corresponds to the component if any. When there is no component on the element, the variable refers to the element itself.

Specifying a value for a local variable allows you to select a specific directive associated with the current element. For example:

```
<input #name="ngForm" ngControl="name" [(ngModel)]="company.name"/>
```

will set the instance of the `ngForm` directive associated with the current in the `name` variable.

So local variables don't target what you want, i.e. setting a value created for the current element of a loop.

If you try to do something like that:

```
<div *ngFor="#elt of eltList" >
  <span #localVariable="elt.title"></span>
  {{localVariable}}
</div>
```

You will have this following error:

```
Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "elt.title" ("
  <div *ngFor="#elt of eltList" >
    <span [ERROR ->]#localVariable="elt.title"></span>
    {{localVariable}}
  </div>
"): AppComponent@2:10
```

Angular2 actually looks for a directive matching the provided name `elt.title` here)... See this plunkr to reproduce the error: https://plnkr.co/edit/qcMGr9FS7yQD8LbX18uY?p=preview

See this link: http://victorsavkin.com/post/119943127151/angular-2-template-syntax, section "Local variables" for more details.

In addition to the current element of the iteration, `ngFor` only provides a set of exported values that can be aliased to local variables: `index`, `last`, `even` and `odd`.

See this link: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgFor-directive.html

What you could do is to create a sub component to display elements in the loop. It will accept the current element as parameter and create your "local variable" as attribute of the component. You will be able then to use this attribute in the template of the component so it will be created once per element in the loop. Here is a sample:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'elt',
  template: `
    <div>{{attr}}</div>
  `
})
export class ElementComponent {
  @Input() element;

  constructor() {
    // Your old "localVariable"
    this.attr = createAttribute(element.title);
  }

  createAttribute(_title:string) {
    // Do some processing
    return somethingFromTitle;
  }
}
```

and the way to use it:

```
<div *ngFor="#elt of eltList" >
  <elt [element]="elt></elt>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you are correct.  I was hoping for an easier way but it doesn't look possible right now.  IMHO it would be very nice if there was a syntax for setting locally variables to results of template expressions.  It could make this type of usage a bit easier.

Comment: Yes, agreed! I posted an issue in the Angular github to know if there is something planned regarding this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6947.

Comment: It's important to note the slight change on the ngFor: `*ngFor="let myVar of list"`. Check it out: (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgFor-directive.html)

Answer (score 17):

I think this is a classic case for making a subcomponent.

```
<td *ngFor="#prod of products">
    <subComp [prod]=prod></subComp>
</td>
```

Your component would then have a `prod` input and run the required function once in `OnInit`.

Simple example plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lCAygOYkTyPwYm0iHZjS?p=preview)

Comment: I could create a sub component that takes branch and prod as inputs.  Just seems heavy weight for something that is a few lines of HTML that could be done in the "parent" component template.  I was hoping for some way to assign a variable inside the ngFor and use it in the body of the loop.

Answer (score 15):

With angular 4 you can do this:

```
<td *ngFor="#prod of products">
  <div *ngIf="getBuild(branch,prod); let build">
    <a href="{{build.url}}">
     {{build.status}}
    </a>
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 6):

Although arguments can be made about the advantages of simply writing a new subcomponent. I think that the following solution is the most correct answer to the question asked.

```html
<div *ngFor="let person of listOfPeople">
  <ng-container
    *ngTemplateOutlet="introText; context: { title: getTitle(person), color: person.color }"
  ></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #introText let-title="title" let-color="color">
  <p [style.color]="color">
    {{title}} loves the color {{color}}
  </p>
</ng-template>
```

Check out a [codesandbox of this](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-panini-7skfi?file=/src/app/app.component.html).
This will allow for defining multiple template variables, and reusing the output of a calculation an unlimited number of times.

**Reasons to use ng-template:**

- As OP mentioned, this is lighter weight than a whole new component. Therefore this may be a good option if you have a *simple* template that reuses calculated logic
- In
  some cases the template NEEDS to be in the same file - I ran into
  this with a 'mat-stepper' (Material library) component for example

**Reasons to avoid ng-template:**

- If the code should be reusable in other components
- If the template gets too complex, it will become far more confusing than helpful

Answer (score 4):

Improving on the *ngIf solution, you can have always true condition to leave no culprits

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ng-container *ngIf="getMyVariableValue(item.id) || true; let myVariable">
        {{ content here }}
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

One observation I want to note, Angular doesn't put the exact return value of the function (here, "getMyVariableValue"). If it returns **null** or **undefined** then Angular will put **true** in "myVariable".

Answer (score 2):

No, just cache the result in `getBuild` for each `branch`/`prod` combination or as long as it is called with the same values as before.

Comment: Understood that I could cache the results.  The issue isn't that the computation takes a long time (it is already cached).  It is just that I don't want to repeat the call multiple times in the body of the for loop.  I was hoping for a way to conceptually do:  "build = getBuild(branch,prod)" and then just use build inside the loop.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible. If the computation isn't expensive I wouldn't bother anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Though not ideal, another approach could be using *ngIf

```
<td *ngFor="#prod of products">
  <ng-container *ngIf="{build:getBuild(branch,prod)}; let state">
    <a href="{{state.build?.url}}">
      {{state.build?.status}}
    </a>
  </ng-container>
</td>
```

Since the *ngIf expression returns an object, it will always be thruthy so the content inside ng-container will always be rendered. The resulting object gets assigned to the state variable which can be reused later on. The ng-container does not insert an dom element.

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as another already posted. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53558536/31532

Comment: the original answer does not take into account if the getBuild(branch, prod) method returns a non-truthy value. Using an object allows you to always ensure that the container is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with a bit of a hack, you can also loop over a single-item list:

```html
<td *ngFor="#prod of products">
  <a *ngFor="let build of [getBuild(branch,prod)]" href="{{build?.url}}">
    {{build?.status}}
   </a>
</td>
```