# Write ngFor result into variable using Angular 2

Tags: angular

Using AngularJS i can do it:

```
item in (filteredList.sup = (nozzles | rangeFilter: { flow: calc.q.tempFlow, pressure: calc.pressure } | orderBy: 'pressao'))
```

I've made a ng-repeat and the result of them, i have set into **filteredList.sup** variable.

I'm trying to do the same using Angular 2, but isn't so easy as AngularJS *(I'm new on Angular 2)*

.

I tried:
[ng2: How to create variable in ngFor loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35257455/ng2-how-to-create-variable-in-ngfor-loop)

and

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2451

Without success! :/

**PS* If i can use my pipes inside the "controller"/component.ts  it can help too.**

Actual code:

```
listService.ended
    | filterBy: { empresaId: selectedCompany }
    | filterOperador: filtroOperador
    | dateRange: dateRange.min : dateRange.max
```

filterBy = https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-filter-pipe

filterOperador & dateRange = Custom Pipes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular2, it can't be implemented, but as mentioned [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgForOf-directive.html) in Angular4, you can implement this again just like we did in `angularjs`.

```
*ngFor="let user of userObservable | async as results;
```

---

> If i can use my pipes inside the "controller"/component.ts it can help too.

yes, if you don't mind using Pipe twice in template and component, you can call your pipes at component this way:

```
// inject the Pipe
constructor(pipe: XXXPipe){}

getPipeResult() {
  // call Pipe's transform
  let pipeResult = this.pipe.transform(input, arg1, arg2, ...)
}
```

Comment: Great! The pipes in logical file has worked fine, i've added on app.module > providers to call inside the constructor

Comment: And i did a "merge" of pipes, because calling 4 different pipes has made my app slow.

Comment: @HelcioMacedo glad it helped.