# How to apply a condition repeatedly in an ngFor loop?

Tags: angular

I have a fairly straightforward use-case; a tabular list of users, each of whom might be *active* or not. Depending on which it is, the row is styled differently. The conditional style is applied in **more than one** place:

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users" [ngClass]="{'not-active': user.status !== 'ACT'}">
<td>{{user.username}}</td>
<td>{{user.status}}</td>
<td>
  <button [disabled]="user.status !== 'ACT'">Edit</button>
  <button [disabled]="user.status === 'ACT'">Activate</button></a>
</td>
```

Obviously, this is not very good since I have to spell out my conditional logic three times. It would be much nicer if I could write:

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users; let isActive = user.status === 'ACT';"
        [ngClass]="{'not-active': !isActive}">
<td>{{user.username}}</td>
<td>{{user.status}}</td>
<td>
  <button [disabled]="!isActive">Edit</button>
  <button [disabled]="isActive">Activate</button></a>
</td>
```

However, I understand from reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35257455/ng2-how-to-create-variable-in-ngfor-loop) and others that this is currently not possible.

The proposed workaround from the post above is to create a component that contains an HTML template (for the table row?) and then to do the logic in the component class. This seems quite an overhead for a relatively simple requirement...

So before diving in, I'd like to ask if this is truly the canonical solution to this type of problem?

In response to a comment, I have implemented a simple example of the issue on [stackblitz](https://angular-h9wmty.stackblitz.io) (I've not used this before... can you see my codebase?).

Comment: can you reproduce stackblitz for this?????

Comment: @Sanoj_V Now on stackblitz https://angular-h9wmty.stackblitz.io (can you see the code?)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: The answer is no, U can't declare a scope variable within a *nfFor

The only way I think u can achieve that is by wrapping the tr content into something and using a `*ngIf`. Something like:

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users">
    <div *ngIf="user.status === 'ACT'; let isActive" [ngClass]="{'not-active': !isActive}">

      <td>{{user.username}}</td>
     <td>{{user.status}}</td>
     <td>
        <button [disabled]="!isActive">Edit</button>
         <button [disabled]="isActive">Activate</button></a>
     </td>
</div>
```

(I can't close the `tr` tag)

But by using on this way you aren't going to aply the `not-active` class to the table row, but to the inside div

Comment: Thanks for your reply - this is a good solution when dealing with <div> and <li> but, you're right, it messes up table tags. Hopefully this (rather obvious) use-case will be introduced in some future upgrade.